# Fibonnacci numbers less than set value

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

Why does this piece of code not generate fibonacci numbers less than the set value.

```
from math import sqrt
def Fib(n):
    return round(((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5)))

def Fiblessthan(m):
    total = [0]
    count = 1
    while max(total) < m:
        total.append(Fib(count))
        count = count + 1
```

For example i won't it to be able to print all the fibonacci numbers less than 4000000. Is this the right way to approach this.

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `max(total) < m`

Comment: `while max(total) > m:` isn't true at the beginning.
And your fib function isn't the best to calculate the fib value here!

Comment: Wikunia what is the best fib function.

Comment: Warning: your function stops working at n=71 because of the limited precision.  Your `Fib` returns  308061521170130.0, when the answer is  308061521170129.

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import sqrt
def Fib(n):
    return round(((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5)))

def Fiblessthan(m):
    total = [0]
    count = 1
    while total[-1] < m:
        total.append(Fib(count))
        count = count + 1
    return total
```

you have to check for length of total less than m.

Comment: Than returns a list on fibonacci numbers that is the lenght of the input. I wanted a function that produces fibonacci numbers up to a certain value

Comment: @phighter modified it as you want :)